# Django Autocomplete-Light not working under python 2.7.6

Tags: python, django, autocomplete

My development environment is running python 2.7.1 and the production is running 2.7.6

The code below is working fine on development, but doesn't fire the autocomplete for the new_city field on production:

**Admin.py**

```
class LocationAdminForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):

    class Media:
        js = ('dependant_autocomplete.js',)


    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'instagram_id', 'country', 'new_country', 'city', 'new_city']


class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'country', 'city', 'new_country', 'new_city']
    search_fields = ['name', 'new_country', 'new_city']
    list_editable = []
    list_filter = ['new_city', 'new_country']

    form = LocationAdminForm
```

**autocomplete-registry.py**

```
class AutocompleteCity(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'city name ..'}

    def choices_for_request(self):
        q = self.request.GET.get('q', '')
        country_id = self.request.GET.get('country_id', None)

        choices = self.choices.all()
        if q:
            choices = choices.filter(name__icontains=q)
        if country_id:
            choices = choices.filter(country_id=country_id, name__icontains=q)

        return self.order_choices(choices)[0:self.limit_choices]

autocomplete_light.register(Location, AutocompleteCity)

autocomplete_light.register(City, search_fields=('name'),
    autocomplete_js_attributes={'placeholder': 'city name ..'})
```

Any idea on what could be the reason for this or how I can troubleshoot it?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the autocomplete-light docs, I was missing the following in the LocationAdminForm:

```
        widgets = autocomplete_light.get_widgets_dict(Location)
```